# .Net Core and Node.JS Version Control

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, git, .net-core

I have a .Net Core project and a Node.JS project. As they refer to the same thing, I want to put both projects in the same location in TFS using GIT. What would be the best way to do this, since I can not add a folder in a Visual Studio solution? Is it possible to separate these projects only in one folder?

To develop in .Net Core I am using visual studio 2017 and to develop in node.js I am using Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 0):

You can break down your directory structure of your repo as follows

`src/my-dotnet-app` This will be the root of your Visual Studio related files and your .NET code

`src/my-node-app` This will be the root of your Node.JS application

When you open your .NET solution using Visual Studio, it won't see anything related to the Node.JS applicaiton. When you open your Node.JS code in VS Code, use `my-node-app` as the root to ignore any of the .NET code.

Comment: How can I create this structure on VSTS? VSTS just give me root path

Comment: If this is a git repository as you mentioned, you can create the directories via the command line, create your solutions in the right place, and then commit them.